# Avoiding No data driven pages were created error in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, data-driven-pages

I am trying to enable Data Driven Pages in my mapdocument but I keep getting an error that says:

> No data driven pages were created. Please verify that the index layer
>   has a valid source and contains features for a page creation.

I know that that my layer "polytrial selection 5" exists.

What is happening?

I added some screenshots for more context.

[image].

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to create Data Driven Pages you will need to have a Name Field chosen - in your graphic of the Data Driven Pages Setup there is not one.

If you are not offered a choice for this field, then it will be because your Index Layer has no text field available to use for your page names, so add and populate one.